# Recursive method for prime numbers in JAVA

Tags: java, recursion, boolean

First of all I know this is kind of a simple question and I am a beginner so please bear with me .
I have been having problems with this exercise in Java and I'm practising for a test and this one really messed up my self-confidence.
So anyways the problem looks like this

```
 // Returns true if (and only if) n is a prime number;  n > 1 is assumed.
private static boolean isPrime(long n) {
    return isPrime(n, 2);
    // See the method isPrime below.
}

// Helper method for isPrime ...
private static boolean isPrime(long n, long m) {
    return (m * n > (m /* TODO: modify expression if necessary */))
            || (n % m == (0 /* TODO: modify expression if necessary */)
                && isPrime((m /* TODO: modify expression if necessary */), n + 1));
}
```

So you're supposed to fill these expressions inside of the brackets where TODO is . 
My problem is that I just can't trace what this does.

```
isPrime((.....),n+1);
```

If someone could just offer some advice on how to start solving this problem I would be very grateful .

Comment: A number is only prime if it's divisible by only 1 and itself.  The complementary statement of that is that it's NOT prime if it's evenly divisible (i.e. modulus returns 0) by any other prime.  Should help to think about the problem.

Comment: Yes I understand that , the problem is that the method should return true if the number is prime and the condition where n%m == 0 is true for only not prime numbers. So if n is a prime number that is going to be false , and false && true is still false ..

Comment: `isPrime((m /* TODO: modify expression if necessary */), n + 1))` is checking for the divisor `m`'s primality, not `n`.  If `m` is not prime, `n` is not prime.

Comment: So if we take for example `n=7` when the method calls itself for the first time the m parameter is 8 ?

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I'm not entirely sure what the answer is, because this is kind of a weird way to recurse.  Normally you'd recurse with `isPrime(n, m+1)`, but your question transposes `m` and `n`.

Comment: Yeah thats why I was getting confused ,  I really appreciate the help , thanks !

Comment: this exercise is really messed up, because you must modify code *outside* of brackets where the TODO comments are, as well as *inside*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is not amenable to recursive solution.  Or at least not an *efficient* recursive solution.

The definition of primality is that N is prime if it is not divisible by any positive integer other than itself or 1.  The normal way to handle that using recursion would be to define a recursive "is_divisible" function:

```
# for integers m >= 1
is_prime(m):
    return is_divisible(m, 1)

is_divisible(m, n):
    if n >= m: return true
    if n == 1: return is_divisible(m, n + 1)
    if m % n == 0: return false  // HERE
    return is_divisible(m, n + 1)
```

OR (more efficient 3 parameter version)

```
# for all integers m
is_prime(m):
    if m == 1: return false
    if m >= 2: return is_divisible(m, sqrt(m), 2)
    error "m is not a positive integer"

is_divisible(m, max, n) :
    if n >= max: return true
    if m % n == 0: return false  // HERE
    return is_divisible(m, max, n + 1)
```

(In the literature, they often call functions like `is_divisible` "auxiliary" functions.  This is a common tool in functional programming.)

If you try to "optimize" that to only consider prime numbers at `HERE`, you will end up with double recursion .. and exponential complexity.

---

This is all very "unnatural" in Java, and will be horribly inefficient (even compared with a naive primality test using a loop<sup>1</sup>) because Java doesn't do tail-call optimization of recursion.  Indeed, for large enough `N` you will get a `StackOverflowError`.

---

<sup>1 - A better, but still simple approach is the Sieve of Erathones.  There are better tests for primality than that, though they are rather complicated, and in some cases probabilistic.</sup>

Comment: Could we do this with only two paramaters ?
Just use m/2 instead of max ?
`is_divisible(m, n) :-
    if n >= m/2: return true
    if n == 1: return is_divisible(m, n + 1)
    if m % n == 0 : return false  // HERE
    return is_divisible(m, n + 1)`  - something like this ?

Comment: With a 3 parameter version, you should use `sqrt(m)`  as the "max".  The same optimization applies to the naive loop and also to Sieve algorithms.